# NSIS Hide Details after Show Details

Tags: installation, nsis

In my installer, I currently have the "Show Details" button visible, and can click that to get to the installation details.

Is there any way to get a "Hide Details" button at this point to be able to go back to where the details are hidden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no official support for this (Too much space wasted by the button probably)

If you really want this feature and you don't mind hacks you can use this code:

```
Outfile test.exe
RequestExecutionLevel user
!addplugindir ".\" ;http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ButtonEvent_plug-in

!include WinMessages.nsh
!include LogicLib.nsh

Page InstFiles "" PageInstShow

!define GWLP_ID -12
!define IDC_DETAILS 0x3F8
!define IDC_SHOWDETAILS 0x403
!define IDC_MYTOGGLE 0x1000

Function MyToggleClickHandler
FindWindow $9 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $8 $9 ${IDC_MYTOGGLE}
GetDlgItem $7 $9 ${IDC_DETAILS}
System::Call 'user32::IsWindowVisible(ir7)i.r0'
${If} $0 = 0
    SendMessage $9 ${WM_COMMAND} ${IDC_SHOWDETAILS} 0
    SendMessage $8 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:Hide &details"
    ShowWindow $8 1
${Else}
    SendMessage $8 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(^ShowDetailsBtn)"
    ShowWindow $7 0
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd

Function PageInstShow
FindWindow $9 "#32770" "" $HWNDPARENT
GetDlgItem $8 $9 ${IDC_SHOWDETAILS}
System::Call 'user32::SetWindowLong(ir8,i ${GWLP_ID},i ${IDC_MYTOGGLE})'
GetFunctionAddress $1 MyToggleClickHandler
ButtonEvent::AddEventHandler ${IDC_MYTOGGLE} $1
System::Call '*(i,i,i,i)i.r1'
System::Call 'user32::GetWindowRect(ir8,ir1)'
System::Call 'user32::MapWindowPoints(i0,ir9,ir1,i2)'
System::Call '*$1(i,i,i,i.r6)'
GetDlgItem $7 $9 ${IDC_DETAILS}
System::Call 'user32::GetWindowRect(ir7,ir1)'
System::Call 'user32::MapWindowPoints(i0,ir9,ir1,i2)'
System::Call '*$1(i.r2,i.r3,i.r4,i.r5)'
System::Free $1
IntOp $3 $6 + 4 ; list top = button bottom + padding
IntOp $5 $5 - $3
System::Call 'user32::SetWindowPos(ir7,i,ir2,ir3,ir4,ir5,i 0)'
FunctionEnd

Section
SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1):

From NSIS Scripting Reference documentation:

> [4.8.1.34 ShowInstDetails](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html#4.8.1.34)
>
> **hide**|show|nevershow
>
> Sets whether or not the details of the install are shown. Can be
>   'hide' to hide the details by default, allowing the user to view them,
>   or 'show' to show them by default, or 'nevershow', to prevent the user
>   from ever seeing them. Note that sections can override this using
>   SetDetailsView.